# Add custom link to SharePoint list settings page by code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, custom-action

I would like to add a custom link to a SharePoint list settings page (listedit.aspx) from code, I have searched the web and Stack Overflow, and can't seem to find any examples or documentation on doing this specifically.

There are a dozen examples on how to do this from the elements.xml and on deployment/activation, but I would like to do this from C# code, like this:

```
SPUserCustomAction customAction = spCustomList.UserCustomActions.Add();
customAction.Url = "someurlhere";
customAction.Name = "CustomName";
customAction.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.ListSettings";
customAction.Title = "Custom Settings";
customAction.Update();
spCustomList.Update();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your Location is incorrect and you need a Group.

Try the following:

```
SPUserCustomAction customAction = spCustomList.UserCustomActions.Add();
customAction.Url = "someurlhere";
customAction.Name = "CustomName";
customAction.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit";
customAction.Group = "GeneralSettings";
customAction.Title = "Custom Settings";
customAction.Update();
```

For more information on Locations, see [Default Custom Action Locations and IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx).

Comment: @user80130 please click on the checkmark if this answer is correct and click the up arrow if you like this answer. Thanks.

Comment: In extend of this - do you know how to create a Custom Group too ?

Comment: The comments section is not a good place for questions and answers. You should start a new question on how to create custom groups.